# Is this an unsafe Apache Rewrite Rule?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've got a rewrite rule set up like this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cache/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ cache/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Brief explanation for this rule: it checks to see if a requested file exists in the cache directory. If it does, then it serves the cache directory.

E.g. a request to http://somehost.tld/about.html
would be served from http://somehost.tld/cache/about.html (if this file exists).

What I'm concerned about is if the RewriteRule is insecure.  Is it possible for someone to request a URL like this, with double periods in it to move up a directory:

http://somehost.tld/../../private_file.txt

So causing private_file.txt to be served from a directory above my apache public folder?

Comment: BTW I did try this out but my results were inconclusive on my server, I think its safe, but I'm not certain...

Comment: My guess is that Apache would deny access to the file `private_file.txt`. However a determined attacker could possibly test for the presence of `private_file.txt` on your system by the response given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including `..` in a URL doesn't work at either the HTTP request level or the browser level. Browsers just resolve the relative paths, sending a request for the appropriate file (capping it at the server root).  So typing this into an address bar:

```
http://somehost.tld/../../private_file.txt
```

Would result in a HTTP request for:

```
http://somehost.tld/private_file.txt
```

In other words, someone would have to manually craft a HTTP request for the `../..` to reach Apache.  And that comes back with `HTTP 400 Bad Request`.  Example from my local server (which has no rewrite rules):

```
ritsuko:~ spyder$ curl -v http://localhost/../randomfile
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /../randomfile HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.4 (universal-apple-darwin10.0) libcurl/7.19.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8l zlib/1.2.3
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Wed, 17 Feb 2010 13:18:40 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.13 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.13 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2
< Content-Length: 226
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
* Closing connection #0
```

Answer (score 0):

[apache](http://apache.org) doesn't allow 'move up a directory'.